# Problemas com referências e MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho um projeto onde funciona. Precisei criar outro projeto em outro lugar e fui aproveitando o que eu já possuo. Acontece que está dando um erro em base.Initialize(...) dizendo que não reconhece esse cara. Coloquei os mesmos using do outro projeto, ou seja, ctrl+c e ctrl+v e nada mais. Abaixo meus métodos

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {

            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Expires = 0;
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            string strPaginaAtual = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath;
            strPaginaAtual = strPaginaAtual.Remove(0, strPaginaAtual.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            base.Initialize(requestContext);

        }

        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {

            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
```

e meus usings:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Fui compilar e deu esse erro:

```
Error   1   'V99Util.WebPageBase.Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext)': no suitable method found to override
```

Comment: Qual a classe base da classe `WebPageBase`?

Comment: @pnet, o lugar para publicar a solução do problema é numa Resposta e não dentro da Pergunta. Aparentemente, é a mesma solução que o Cigano postou, quiçá marcar a resposta dele como correta?

Answer (score 2):

A mensagem `no suitable method found to override` indica que na classe ancestral não existe um método `Initialize` que seja `virtual` com os argumentos usados no método da classe filho.

Neste caso, sua classe precisa ser implementada com a seguinte declaração:

```
public abstract class WebPageBase : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
```

Comment: Perito em pnet. ;)

Comment: Daqui a pouco vão criar a Tag.

Comment: E a aceitação automática para a tag.